# como voltar um commit sem carregar as alterações

Tags: git, github

```
# tentando reverter commits sem carregar alterações #
```

Eu estou tentando apreender á usar HTML2CANVAS,html2canvas é uma biblioteca em html utilizada para  se  capturar  a parte visível de sites da internet  feitas em html. para um projeto da  faculdade onde estudo , contudo não consegui e terminei gerando três commits com o código problemático , para poder compartilhar o código problemático com meus colegas de grupo .  Agora que já dei os commits estou tentando voltar a branch ha um momento onde  as alterações  não foram feitas  estes  não aparecerem   já tentei   com Git checkout e Git reset --hard

Comment: `git reset --hard <commit-hash>` (altera o conteúdo do arquivo) ou `git reset --soft <commit-hash>` (não altera o conteúdo) ou `git checkout <commit-hash> -- /path/to/file` ou `git revert <commit-hash>` ou `git restore -s <commit-hash> /path/to/file`

Comment: gostaria de agradecer ao ValdeirPsr , pois ele respondeu minha pergunta.